# Equation demonstration

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, floating-point

Let $\delta f \equiv \frac{\Delta f}{f}$ show that:

$$\matrix{\delta(xy) &=& \delta x + \delta y\\
\delta(x/y) &=& \delta x - \delta y\\
\delta(x+y) &=& \frac{x}{x+y}{\delta x} + \frac{y}{x+y}{\delta y}}$$

Using floating point arithmetics, I am trying to demonstrate those formulas. For the first formula, I have tried something like this: I know that $f(xy)= f(x)f(y)$

$$\Delta f \approx \sum_{i=1}^n\Delta x_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

But I got stuck even at the first equation. Any guidance, example or help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does δ mean in this context?

Comment: I think it must be a floating-point error in $x$ or $y$.

Comment: I edited your question, check and see that the meaning is not altered. See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to properly typeset math using mathjax.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, yes, it is the floating point relative error.

Comment: @Winther, Yes, it is correct. Thank you for the link, didn't know exactly the way to format, it is usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ of two variables (which we assume is differentiable) and we want to determine how much the function value $f(x,y)$ change if we make a small change $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$ to the point $(x,y)$. This change is denoted as

$$\Delta f(x,y) \equiv f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y) - f(x,y)$$

From a Taylor expansion we have that to first order in the small quantities $\Delta x,\Delta y$ this change is given by

$$\Delta f(x,y) \simeq \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\Delta y$$

diving by $f(x,y)$ and using the definition of $\delta[f]= \frac{\Delta f}{f}$ we can write the equation as (dropping the $(x,y)$ label for simplicity)

$$\delta f \simeq \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y$$

We can manipulate it further by using that $\delta x=\frac{\Delta x}{x}$ and $\delta y=\frac{\Delta y}{y}$ to arrive at

$$\delta f \simeq \left(\frac{x}{f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\delta x + \left(\frac{y}{f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\delta y$$

The formula above, and the abillity to compute derivatives is all you need to solve the problem at hand. You need to apply it to the three functions $f_1(x,y) = xy$, $f_2(x,y) = x/y$, $f_3(x,y) = x+y$. I will below give an example for the first case.

For the function $f_1(x,y) = xy$ we have $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} = y$ and $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} = x$ which gives $\frac{x}{f_1}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{xy}\cdot y = 1$ and $\frac{y}{f_1}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{xy}\cdot x = 1$. Using this the equation above says that

$$\delta [xy] \simeq \delta x + \delta y$$

Comment: So in this case, for f1(x,y) = xy and f2(x,y)=x/y, based on the last line logic, it will also prove not only the first equation, but also the second one with delta(x/y). Am I right? Also, very helpfull answer, I really got it now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the complex answer and for giving a way to solve it, without giving the full solution. I will try to solve the last 2 ones and post an answer. I will accept your answer and if I have any question, could you please check if what I did was right?

Comment: @SimplyMe The $f_1$ result does not imply the $f_2$ result. You will have to compute the derivatives for $f_2$ and use the formula to get this result. Positing a complete answer is a good idea, let me know once you have done it and I will happily check it.

Comment: @SimplyMe You cannot delete the question (just try) once it has upvoted answers, only the community can.

Comment: Can I write here in comments what I got for 2nd equation?

Comment: @SimplyMe Yes you can.

Comment: @SimplyMe That is correct. Using your results we see that $\frac{x}{(x/y)}\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{x}{(x/y)} \frac{1}{y} = 1$ and $\frac{x}{(x/y)}\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{y}{(x/y)} (-\frac{x}{y^2} = -1$ which gives the correct result.

Comment: Oh, you can edit even in comments? On SO it does not work that way, I think. Sorry for that format.

Comment: thanks! I actually managed to understand it. Thanks for not giving full answer, now I was able to find the rest myself and understand your demonstration!

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:
$$\delta(xy)=\frac{\Delta(xy)}{xy}=\frac{(x+\Delta x)(y+\Delta y)-xy}{xy}=\frac{xy+x\Delta. y+\Delta x. y+\Delta x.\Delta y-xy}{xy}=\frac{x.\Delta y+\Delta x. y+\Delta x.\Delta y}{xy}=\delta y+\delta x+\delta x\delta y\sim \delta x+\delta y$$
because the term $\delta x\delta y$ is neglectable compared to the first two.

For the second problem:
$$\delta\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\frac{\frac{x+\Delta x}{y+\Delta y}-\frac{x}{y}}{\frac{x}{y}}=\frac{xy+y\Delta x-xy-x\Delta y}{y(y+\Delta y)}\cdot\frac{y}{x}=\frac{y\Delta x-x\Delta y}{x(y+\Delta y)}$$
$$=\delta x\cdot\frac{y}{y+\Delta y}-\frac{\Delta y}{y+\Delta y}\sim\delta x-\delta y$$
because $$\frac{y}{y+\Delta y}=\frac{1}{\frac{y+\Delta y}{y}}=\frac{1}{1+\delta y}\sim 1$$ and 
$$\frac{\Delta y}{y+\Delta y}=\frac{\Delta y/y}{1+\Delta y/y}=\frac{\delta y}{1+\delta y}\sim \delta y$$
Above we assumed that $\delta y<< 1$, which is true if $\Delta y<<y$, i.e if $y$ is much larger than the machine precision $\Delta y$.

The third problem is done analogously.

Comment: I like your answer. It has another perspective and it is great as well! Thank you!